# Is this true that Sri Ramakrishna predicted that in future, he will be worshipped in every household?

Tags: ramakrishna

One monk from Ramakrishna Mission came to our village. In his lecture, he said that Sri Ramakrishna predicted that one day he will be worshipped in every household in this world. Is it true? Is there any reference?

Comment: This statement is found in the biography of Sri Ramakrishna written by his direct disciple, Swami Saradananda.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Why don't you quote the relevant section as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the reference in this [book](https://estudantedavedanta.net/Ramakrishna_As_We_Saw_Him.pdf):

Reminiscence of Sri Ramakrishna by Holy Mother Sarada Devi:

> Once when the Master was lying ill at Cossipore a few devotees brought
> some offerings for Mother Kali at the Dakshineshwar temple. On hearing
> that the Master was at Cossipore they offered everything they had
> brought before a picture of the Master, and then partook of the
> prasad. When the Master heard this, he remarked, "All these things
> were brought for the great Mother of the Universe, and they have
> offered them here [meaning himself]!" I was frightened very much at
> this and thought: "He is suffering from this dangerous disease. Who
> knows what might happen? What a calamity! Why did they do it? *"
>
> The Master too referred to this incident again and again. Afterwards,
> at a late hour in the night, he said to me: **"You will see how in the
> course of time I will be worshipped in every house. You will see
> everyone accepting this [meaning himself]. This is surely going to
> happen."** That was the only day I heard him using the first person with
> reference. Usually he would speak of himself not as "I" or "me", but
> as "this case" or as "belonging to this," pointing to his body.
>
> *It is sacrilegious to offer a man the gifts that are meant for a deity, and hence this fear that it may cause some misfortune.

**~Ramakrishna As We Saw Him - p.29,30
Edited and Translated by Swami Chetanananda.**